# fingerprint listener without dialog wiith new api

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to implement fingerprint authentication in my app with `new biometric api`. But the problems is how can I implement it without `fingerprint authentication dialog`. Thank you for your response!

Comment: The dialog is fairly important for some forms of biometrics. For example, for an in-screen fingerprint reader, the user needs to know where to place their finger.

Comment: yeah. You are right. I didn't think about it as my phone is simple one. Thank you for your explanation!